# iOS - tableview multiple displays

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

i am displaying webview inside tableview cell but when i scroll up and down its displays multiple of same web view

please check my following code

```
videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                   <html>\
                   <head>\
                                         </head>\
                   <body>\
                   <iframe  src=\"%@\" ></iframe>\
                   </body>\
                   </html>", videoURL];

UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

ccell.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

[ccell.contentView addSubview:videoView];

[videoView loadHTMLString:[videoHTML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br/>"] baseURL:nil];
```

please stuck here for 4 hours now can't find how this to be done

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ReusableCell`, when you get the `ReuseableCell`, the cell may already has a `videoView`, and you add another `videoView`. This will cause "its displays multiple of same web view".

You can check whether the cell has a `videoView`, or use custom cell and add a `UIWebView` property.

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCellIdentifier"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] init];
    cell.videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.videoView];
}

videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
               <html>\
               <head>\
                                     </head>\
               <body>\
               <iframe  src=\"%@\" ></iframe>\
               </body>\
               </html>", videoURL];


[cell.videoView loadHTMLString:[videoHTML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br/>"] baseURL:nil];
```